# Devise Confirmable -- How To Disable Confirmation Feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

According to this issue, if I do not require my users to "confirm" their account after creating it, then I can pass this option to the config, `config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = nil`, which I found in [this issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2275#issuecomment-230107505). However, what is unclear to me is the rest of the configuration for confirmable:

**i)** Do I need update my Devise User model with `devise :confirmable`? Right now it looks like this and does not have `:confirmable` passed:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
```

**ii)** Also, what needs to change with regards to the migration file? With `config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = nil`, do I need to uncomment the confirmable fields in my migration file as specified in [these docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users#create-a-new-migration)? Or do I leave the comments alone?

Currently I am using Rails `6.0.1` and Devise `4.7.1`.

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? Do you have an app that with confirmable and you want to remove the feature? Or do you just want to create an app without confirmable (which is the default for devise)?

Comment: Or do you want for some really strange reason to create an app with confirmable that doesn't require confirmation at all?

Comment: Hi @max, I want to "create an app without confirmable" -- in other words, I want to create an app where my users do not need to confirm their account.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, are you saying that I do not need to make any code changes? I just leave the User model, the migrations and the config as it was created with the devise generated `$ rails generate devise user`.

Comment: Yeah thats the devise default so you don't have to do anything. Confirmable is opt-in.

Comment: @max that is interesting because here, https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/generators/templates/devise.rb#L139-L140, it suggests to set `config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for` to `nil`.

Comment: But then as you suggested, the comments go on to say that `nil` is the default https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/generators/templates/devise.rb#L149-L150 so :shrug:

Comment: Thats under the segment `# ==> Configuration for :confirmable`. The configuration setting also does absolutely nothing unless you have `devise ..., :confirmable` in your model. Its also commented out.

Comment: Ok thank you @max I think I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confirmable module is not enabled by default. To "disable" it you just remove the module name from the call to the `devise` method in the model:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable 
end
```

The `config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for` setting does absolutely nothing without the confirmable module enabled.

The reason you would want to use `config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = nil` is if you want to use `Devise::Confirmable` to confirm emails but not use it to restrict authorization. Many apps for example restrict certain features to users that have confirmed their email - but you can still log in how ever long you want with an unconfirmed email.